Best rank r approximation of a matrix with wildcard elements?
Let's say you have a $n \times n$ matrix, for example, this $4 \times 4$ matrix:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & d \\\ e & f & g & h \\\ i & j & k & l \\\ m & n & o & p \end{bmatrix}$$
and you want to compute a rank $r$ approximation of this matrix to minimize the MSE. Normally we can use SVD to truncate the lowest $(n-r)$ singular values, and multiply the $r$ resulting vectors and singular values to get the resulting matrix.
But how do you compute the best rank $r$ approximation of this matrix (minimizing MSE) with wildcard elements? For example, if instead the matrix is:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & * & c & * \\\ * & * & * & h \\\ i & j & * & l \\\ * & n & o & * \end{bmatrix}$$
and when calculating the MSE of the rank $r$ matrix, the error term associated with the wildcard elements diminish to 0? Specifically, the MSE calculation only considers the terms $a, c, h, i, j, l, n, \text{and } o$?
Another way to frame this problem is, how do you calculate the best rank $r$ approximation matrix (minimizing MSE) of:
$$f(A, B) = A \cdot B \quad\quad\quad \text{(Hadamard product)} \\\\
\text{where } A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & d \\\ e & f & g & h \\\ i & j & k & l \\\ m & n & o & p \end{bmatrix} \\\\
B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

If you want to write eg "a $n \times n$, matrix" use the Latex command `\times :)

Thanks! I have edited it
